# Python style - line continuation with strings?

Tags: python, coding-style

In trying to obey the python style rules, I've set my editors to a max of 79 cols.

In the PEP, it recommends using python's implied continuation within brackets, parentheses and braces.  However, when dealing with strings when I hit the col limit, it gets a little weird.

For instance, trying to use a multiline

```
mystr = """Why, hello there
wonderful stackoverflow people!"""
```

Will return

```
"Why, hello there\nwonderful stackoverflow people!"
```

This works:

```
mystr = "Why, hello there \
wonderful stackoverflow people!"
```

Since it returns this:

```
"Why, hello there wonderful stackoverflow people!"
```

But, when the statement is indented a few blocks in, this looks weird:

```
do stuff:
    and more stuff:
        and even some more stuff:
            mystr = "Why, hello there \
wonderful stackoverflow people!"
```

If you try and indent the second line:

```
do stuff:
    and more stuff:
        and even some more stuff:
            mystr = "Why, hello there \
            wonderful stackoverflow people!"
```

Your string ends up as:

```
"Why, hello there                wonderful stackoverflow people!"
```

The only way I've found to get around this is:

```
do stuff:
    and more stuff:
        and even some more stuff:
            mystr = "Why, hello there" \
            "wonderful stackoverflow people!"
```

Which I like better, but is also somewhat uneasy on the eyes, as it looks like there is a string just sitting in the middle of nowhere.  This will produce the proper:

```
"Why, hello there wonderful stackoverflow people!"
```

So, my question is - what are some people's recommendations on how to do this and is there something I'm missing in the style guide that does show how I should be doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: I indented that much to make a point.  But realize that it's quite easy to reach at least the third level of indentation - but the case still stands that even with one level of indenting, the standard method would make the string wildly out of place.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Since [adjacent string literals are automatically joint into a single string](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation), you can just use the implied line continuation inside parentheses as recommended by PEP 8:

```
print("Why, hello there wonderful "
      "stackoverflow people!")
```

Comment: Thanks Sven, I like this a bit more than the style I was using.

Comment: I thought this was just a trick but after reading the python doc, I must say, this is neat. Thank you !

Comment: The problem is when assigning to a variable, this form looks too similar to a tuple.  If you add a comma between the strings, it's a tuple with two strings.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to put the space on the first line instead of the second line?

Comment: @Stevoisiak That's definitely my preference, but either way is fine I guess.

Comment: Interesting , for those wondering how with f-string  
`print(f'''Why, hello there wonderful  
{variable1} people''')`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45965132/311420

Answer (score 54):

Just pointing out that it is use of parentheses that invokes auto-concatenation. That's fine if you happen to already be using them in the statement. Otherwise, I would just use '\' rather than inserting parentheses (which is what most IDEs do for you automatically). The indent should align the string continuation so it is PEP8 compliant. E.g.:

```
my_string = "The quick brown dog " \
            "jumped over the lazy fox"
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a pretty clean way to do it:

```
myStr = ("firstPartOfMyString"+
         "secondPartOfMyString"+
         "thirdPartOfMyString")
```

Comment: Of all the solutions, this one seemed to be the only one that worked in the case of assigning a parameter to a function by name. That is, foo(text=("bar" + "baz")). So, I'm voting it up.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to use the textwrap module. This also avoids the problem of "string just sitting in the middle of nowhere" as mentioned in the question.

```
import textwrap
mystr = """\
        Why, hello there
        wonderful stackoverfow people"""
print (textwrap.fill(textwrap.dedent(mystr)))
```

Answer (score -2):

I've gotten around this with

```
mystr = ' '.join(
        ["Why, hello there",
         "wonderful stackoverflow people!"])
```

in the past. It's not perfect, but it works nicely for very long strings that need to not have line breaks in them.

Comment: On my machine, this takes 350 ns, joining a tuple instead of a list takes 250 ns.  Implicit joining, on the other hand, only takes 25 ns.  Implicit joining is the clear winner in both simplicity and speed.

Comment: @endolith: I agree that using parentheses is better because it's cleaner, but this is not a place to consider performance. If you care about differences at runtime on the order of 100 ns, particularly when concatenating hard coded strings, something is wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't say caring about 100ns is wrong without knowing the context. What if there are a million operations happening.

Comment: @buffer: This is about formatting hand-coded text for human interpretation. If you do this a million times, you're doing it wrong.  And a million (10^6) times 100 ns (10^-9) is 100 ms (10^-3). 100 nanoseconds is so tiny that multiplying it by a million gives you something that still doesn't take long enough that you should care about it. Like I said, use the (good) accepted answer, but bringing up performance for something like this is ridiculous.

Comment: I wouldn't turn my opinion into judgement without knowing the context.

Comment: @buffer: Did you see the thing about this being handwritten? That's the context.

Comment: @nmichaels, [according to research](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/), 100ms can make a big difference for a user-facing app. Logging performance issues are not uncommon, and then it is often precisely about trading convenient/flexibility of writing '%s...%d...%f...blah-blah-blah' for speed, when suddenly your app is spending precious milliseconds converting integers to strings just so they can be logged.

Comment: @osa Seriously? This is a terrible argument. 100ms is how much extra time it will take to do this **a million times**. We're still talking about concatenating handwritten strings for readability. Performance is not a consideration here. I've done work where 30ns matters. This is not that.