# python code formatting: how to avoid extra spaces within a string that is cut off by the line-breaker "\"

Tags: python, coding-style

I enforce strictly 80 characters per line in my python codes, but occasionally I have to break a line of string into two as following

```
print time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S \
    %p",time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(fname)))
```

in which case the output will have extra spaces in front of the "AM/PM", like

```
foo.dat was last modified: 01/10/2012 02:53:15                    AM
```

There are easy way to fix this, simply to either avoid cutting off strings, or allow long lines in this case, however, I am wondering if there are other more intrinsic ways to tackle this while allowing both str-cutting and line-breaking to happen. The second line is automatically indented by the editor, I don't want to change that either. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python style - line continuation with strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437619/python-style-line-continuation-with-strings)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is to avoid using `\` altogether by using parentheses instead. Also, use the fact that consecutive strings are concatenated into one string. For example:

```
print time.strftime(("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S "
    "%p"), time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(fname)))
```

Comment: You don't even need the extra parens around the string.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
>>> x = "one two three "\
... "four five six"
>>> x
'one two three four five six'
```

For clarity, in a Python source file:

```
x = "one two three "\
"four five six"
```

or

```
print time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S"\
" %p",time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(fname)))
```

Comment: apparently I cannot apply your answer to the example above where the string is actually for formatting, or am I missing something?

Comment: Works for me. That was the Python interpreter shell (i.e. dots are produced by python shell). See my edit for what you'd put in a Python source file.